# LibGDX rhythm game - synchronize camera speed with music

Tags: java, android, libgdx, business-process-management

Hi I am developing LibGDX kind of rhythm game on android. In the game you must click on specific button when "shape" is in black square. I need to synchronize camera speed with music. I was timing camera speed on 60/61 FPS, but when frame rate drop music dislocate.

[My Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jZMK.jpg)

Each "shape" have velocity variable which is stored in *currentVelocity* variable when "shape" is close to the black square.

**Move method:**

```
switch (currentDirection) {
        case UP:
            camera.position.y += currentVelocity;
            for (Actor uiComponent : stage.getActors()) {
                if (!(uiComponent instanceof ShapeObject)) {
                    uiComponent.setY(uiComponent.getY() + currentVelocity);
                }
            }
            break;
        case DOWN:
            camera.position.y -= currentVelocity;
            for (Actor uiComponent : stage.getActors()) {
                if (!(uiComponent instanceof ShapeObject)) {
                    uiComponent.setY(uiComponent.getY() - currentVelocity);
                }
            }
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            camera.position.x += currentVelocity;
            for (Actor uiComponent : stage.getActors()) {
                if (!(uiComponent instanceof ShapeObject)) {
                    uiComponent.setX(uiComponent.getX() + currentVelocity);
                }
            }
            break;
        case LEFT:
            camera.position.x -= currentVelocity;
            for (Actor uiComponent : stage.getActors()) {
                if (!(uiComponent instanceof ShapeObject)) {
                    uiComponent.setX(uiComponent.getX() - currentVelocity);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
```

I know that you must calculate it with BPM, but I have no idea how to do it. To analyze BPM I'm using MixMeister BPM Analyzer.

I'm lost :) Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, the problem were somewhere else:

```
currentVelocity = shapes.get(currentShapeIndex).getVelocity() + Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime
```

If you want to move objects independently:

```
currentVelocity = shapes.get(currentShapeIndex).getVelocity() * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime
```